# Do measurements of commuting obervables really commute?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurement-problem, commutator, observables

Say I have two commuting operators $A$ and $B$, with joint eigenvectors $|n\rangle$.

Say I have a state $S = \sum_n a_n | n \rangle$.  If I measure $A$ first, I pick out say an eigenstate $|k\rangle$ and then measure $B$ which just gives me $|k\rangle$ again.  But if I measure $B$ first, it might pick out a different eigenstate, as $|m\rangle$ and then measuring $A$ gives $|m\rangle$.  So it seems measurements don't necessarily commute unless acting on a joint eigenstate. So my question is whether this statement is true and statements about measurements of commuting observable being order independent is false.

Comment: In quantum mechanics, you can never study individual measurements like this. You must always talk about a collection of measurements and then the probability distribution of outcomes.

Comment: The probability distribution of the results will be identical in both cases.

Comment: That's fine.  But there are a lot of sloppy statements in textbooks about order of measurements.

Answer (score 1):

If the eigenvalues are both degenerate, then this is not really a problem as there is no such "different" eigenstate $|m\rangle$.

If one or both of the eigenspaces is degenerate, though, then the measurement does not return any single eigenvalue - instead, obtaining the result $a$ in a measurement of $A$ will take your state $|\psi\rangle$ and project it to the eigenspace, i.e. the subspace spanned by all the eigenstates of $A$ with eigenvalue $a$. In Dirac notation, this reads
$$
|\psi\rangle\mapsto \Pi_a|\psi\rangle \quad\text{where}\quad \Pi_a = \sum_i|\psi_{a,i}\rangle\langle\psi_{a,i}|,
$$
where the $|\psi_{a,i}\rangle$ are all the different eigenstates of $A$ corresponding to the given eigenvalue.

This means that the question of whether measurements of compatible observables commute to the question of whether, if $[A,B]=0$, then $[\Pi_a,\Pi_b]=0$ for all eigenprojectors $\Pi_a$ of $A$ and $\Pi_b$ of $B$; of course, the answer here is yes, though you need to be careful to include *all* the relevant eigenstates in the summation. For more details, see [Commutator with subspaces belonging to the same eigenvalue](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/315564/commutator-with-subspaces-belonging-to-the-same-eigenvalue)

Answer (score 0):

This same argument can be applied to show that a measurement does not commute with itself. Let's take an operator $\hat{A}$ with eigenvectors $\{|n\rangle\}$. Then if our state is $\sum_n a_n|n\rangle$, I can measure once with $\hat{A}$ and get a state $|k\rangle$, and if I measure again with $\hat{A}$, I'll still measure $|k\rangle$.

But now let's do it in the opposite order. I first measure $\hat{A}$ instead of $\hat{A}$. This time, I get a state $|m\rangle$, and if I now measure $\hat{A}$ I stay in $|m\rangle$.

Thus, $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{A}$ don't *really* commute!

---

This should give you an indication that your sense of what "commute" means is wrong, since any sensible definition of "commuting" must have that everything commutes with itself.

Comment: But isn't this the whole point of "contextuality" that measurements in a different context don't necessarily yield the same results.  Measurements aren't projection operators nor represented by the operators themselves.  That is the measurement of AB and CB don't project out the same state even if A and B, or C and B commute.

Comment: Or rather, a measurement of B followed by a measurement of A is different that a measurement of A followed by a measurement of B.  If A=B, then the two statements are the same, so no difference.  But if A not equal to B, we have different statements.

Comment: @JoeB No, the point is that measurement of $AB$ and measurement of $BA$ *are* the exact same thing if $[A,B]=0$.

Comment: I guess what really is happening is that a measurement of AB or BA is not at all the same as a measurement of B followed by a measurement A or vice versa.  E.g., consider a spin one state and the operator Sz or (Sz)^2.  If I measure (Sz)^2 and get 1, the state is left in a combination of Sz= 1 or -1 eigenstates.  But if I first measure Sz, I collapse to either a +1 or -1 eigenstate, and when I do it again, I'm still in either the eignenstate for +1 or -1, and not both.  So the measurement of (Sz)^2 is not the same as the measurement of Sz followed by another measurement of of Sz.

Comment: @JoeB The measurements are not the same, in that you measure different eigenvalues. But the states after measurement are the same. (At least, the probability to be in any specific eigenvector is the same if you measure A and then B, or just measure AB right away.)

Comment: Probabilites to be in a specific eigen state are the same, but the state at the end of a specific measurement is different.

Comment: @JoeB But that's true of ANY measurement. It's true of just measuring A. If you measure A on a state $|\psi\rangle$, you might get a different eigenstate every time. That's JUST like how measuring A and then B gives you a different answer than measuring B and then A. The ONLY reason you get different eigenstates is that you did the measurement process on $|\psi\rangle$ twice. It has NOTHING to do with A and B commuting or not commuting. It is only because measurement is probabilistic in QM.

Comment: But what I'm saying about Sz^2 vs Sz followed by Sz measurement is that the Sz^2 only collapses the state to a two dimensional subspace, if the measurement yields 1,  but Sz measurement collapses the state to a one dimensional subspace, and the next Sz measurement leaves it alone.

Comment: @JoeB That is true, but I didn't see that as the context of your question. I thought you were saying that we shouldn't view "measuring A, then measuring B" as the same process as "measuring B, then measuring A". Either that, or you were saying "Measuring AB and measuring BA are different". My point is they are not different, in any sense of the word. If you conclude measuring AB is different from BA, you have to also conclude measuring $A^2$ is different from measuring $A^2$. And similarly for "measuring A, then measuring A" and "measuring A, then measuring A".

Comment: My question was an off shoot of Kochen Specker and contextuality arguments.  And then I decided I didn't understand what operator multiplication meant (e.g., my field theory reference).  So what I'm seeing is that A^2 measurement is really different that A measurement after A measurement.  So likewise AB measurement is different than B measurement followed by A measurement.  This is not at all clear in talk about contextuality,  Can some similar confusion arise with the notion of addition of operators.  But I ramble.  Thanks for your responses.